# wing panel broken icon app installed via snapd

Tags: wingpanel, icons

I have installed an app via snapd and have changed both .desktop files to point to the svg icon (snap and applications folder) but there's still no icon linking in the wingpanel. any suggestions?

thank you!

[image]